# ERROR is value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

[My codes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsHm0.png)
I do not know why its saying that 'uid' has no member, also i don't know where AuthDataResult is coming from because i have never used this as an import or anything along those lines...

```
@IBAction func signinPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error )
        in
            if error != nil{
                //create account
            } else {

                KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.uid)!,
                forKey: ("Key_UID"))
                self.preformSegue(performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil))
            }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is:

> Value of type `AuthDataResult` has no member `uid`

If you look at the [reference documentation for `AuthDataResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult), you'll see that this is correct: there is no `uid` in that class. The `uid` property exists in `FIRUser`, so you'll want to use:

```
user?.user.uid
```

Or to make it less confusing, give your current `user` variable a name that better matches what it is:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData, error ) in
    if error != nil{
        //create account
    } else {

        KeychainWrapper.standard.set((authData?.user.uid)!,
        forKey: ("Key_UID"))
        self.preformSegue(performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil))
    }
}
```

Comment: im confused I have var: user: String! , and user?.user?.uid in my code right now and I am getting an error that says (Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'User')

Comment: Ah, it turns out that `user` is non-optional in `AuthData`. I updated the code.

Comment: Thank you the concept is weird to me because its like youre pushing an error away with typing actual code, just weird to me probably because im new but thank you Frank you're a great man!!