# Error for Xamarin IOS Firebase AuthDataResult does not Contain ProfileChangeRequest()

Tags: c#, iphone, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm getting an error saying AuthDataResult does not contain ProfileChangeRequest() when i try to change the name of the user. I've to research online and read the firebase docs as well but no luck.

```
public static async Task Register(UIViewController thisView,
                                       string inpName,
                                      string inpEmail,
                                      string inpPassword)
    {
        bool done = false;
        AppDataClass.auth.CreateUser(inpEmail, inpPassword, (user, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                AlertShow.Alert(thisView, "Error",
                                "This went wrong: " + error.UserInfo.Description);
                return;
            }

            UserProfileChangeRequest changeReq = user.ProfileChangeRequest;
            changeReq.DisplayName = inpName;

            changeReq.CommitChanges((profileError) =>
            {
                if (profileError != null)
                {
                    AlertShow.Alert(thisView, "Error",
                                    "Profile Error: " + profileError);
                    return;
                }

                done = true;
            });

        });

        while (!done)
        {
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the document about method [-signInWithEmail:password:completion:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-signinwithemail:password:completion:), the call back it retures is a [FIRAuthDataResultCallback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Type-Definitions.html#firauthdataresultcallback) , the first parameter here is [FIRAuthDataResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuthDataResult).

So the user should be:

```
user.user.ProfileChangeRequest
```

To make it clear:

```
public static async Task Register(UIViewController thisView,
                               string inpName,
                              string inpEmail,
                              string inpPassword)
{
    bool done = false;
    AppDataClass.auth.CreateUser(inpEmail, inpPassword, (authDataResult, error) =>
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            AlertShow.Alert(thisView, "Error",
                            "This went wrong: " + error.UserInfo.Description);
            return;
        }

        UserProfileChangeRequest changeReq = authDataResult.user.ProfileChangeRequest;
        changeReq.DisplayName = inpName;

    });

    while (!done)
    {
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }
}
```

Refer: [ERROR is value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977775/error-is-value-of-type-authdataresult-has-no-member-uid)